# How to use <span> or <p> to display video subtitles

Tags: html, html5-video

I was wondering how I could possibly use `<span>` or `<p>` tag to display video subtitle text (.vtt / .srt) in a `<video>` tag in HTML?

I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find solution.
I want to use a captioning system similar to that YouTube has, I also tried reverse-engineering a YouTube video page via `inspect element` but still no luck.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to generate your own subtitles? There is [built-in functionality for captions already via the use of tracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video)

Comment: Will it be possible to post the code you have written ?

Comment: I do not want to use the built-in `<track>` tag because WebVVT has color formatting and position formatting inside it via CSS, If I want to use a JavaScript video player like videoJS, the WebVVT caption formatting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `<track>` tag specifies text tracks for  or  elements.
This element is used to specify subtitles, caption files or other files containing text, that should be visible when the media is playing.

Tracks are formatted in WebVTT format (.vtt files).

Comment: I am using the `<track>` element, what I am looking for is a script that displays the WebVVT in a `<div>` or `<span>` tag.